# Include inside function considered bad practice?

Tags: php, coding-style, sphinx

I am wondering if it is considered bad practice to include() a library file inside a function?

Part of my website uses the Sphinx search engine, but it seems inefficient to add sphinxapi.php to every single page by including it in my main site-wide 'config' file.

Instead I have done the following:

```
 class sphinxSearch
 {
    /*
    * Performs a standard listing search
    */
     function listings($filter, $sdb)
     {
        // include the sphinx api
        require_once SITE_INCLUDE_PATH.SEP.'Sphinx/sphinxapi.php';

        // set default options
        $search = new SphinxClient();
        $search->SetServer(SPX_HOST, SPX_PORT);
        $search->SetConnectTimeout(1);
        $search->SetArrayResult(false);

        // blah blah blah

        return $result;
    }


    /*
    * Listing autocomplete box
    */  
    function autoComplete ($query, $sdb)
    {
        require_once SITE_INCLUDE_PATH.SEP.'Sphinx/sphinxapi.php';

        // set default options
        $search = new SphinxClient();
        $search->SetServer(SPX_HOST, SPX_PORT);
        $search->SetConnectTimeout(1);
        $search->SetArrayResult(false);

        // blah blah blah

    }
}
```

Or is there a better way that I'm missing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing inherently wrong with this method in my opinion.

One thing that can be done to improve performance on this is to do a `class_exists` call on a class that is implemented in the `sphinxapi.php` and require instead of doing a require_once, this will be especially true if you call the these functions a lot on a single page reload. see [Understanding class required and exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8872898/understanding-class-required-and-exist)

For example:

```
if (!class_exists('SphinxClass')) require "sphinx/shinxapi.php";
```

is faster then

```
require_once "sphinx/shinxapi.php";
```

The best option by far is to set up an autoloader so you don't have to worry about including any files. Have a look at http://phpmaster.com/autoloading-and-the-psr-0-standard/ , it will explain the process.

Answer (score 0):

For all times that you call the function you include the page, then yes, this is a bad practice if there aren't controls, example

```
$path = SITE_INCLUDE_PATH.SEP.'Sphinx/sphinxapi.php';
if(!in_array($path,get_required_files())) require_once $path;
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [PHP-docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) about including:

> When a file is included, parsing drops out of PHP mode and into HTML
>   mode at the beginning of the target file, and resumes again at the
>   end. For this reason, any code inside the target file which should be
>   executed as PHP code must be enclosed within valid PHP start and end
>   tags.

In other words, this will not be a problem if this is what you are intending. HOWEVER, this is not very good OOP-programming. I'd suggesting rewriting your code to extend the `SphinxClient`-class. That would be a much cleaner approach imo.

EDIT: As a final solution, you could include the file in your class' constructor and define a private variable that holds the `SphinxClient`. Like so:

```
private $sphinx;
public function __construct() {
    $this->sphinx = new SphinxClient();
}

// Now you can do: $this->sphinx->method
```

Comment: If sphinxapi.php contains classes, then this is not true. edit: *Searched sphinxapi on google*.. which it definitely is not a class, haha*

Comment: @Anther: OP is writing `$search = new SphinxClient();` in his code. Which means it is a class. If it is public it can get extended (as long as the methods are either public or protected).

Comment: @Anther: What are you talking about? http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.sphinxclient.php is very much a class.

Comment: If it makes any difference, I have an autoloader for my own classes:
`spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {
    include SITE_CLASS_PATH.SEP . $class . '.class.php';
});`

so I could if necessary rename the sphinxapi.php and dump it in my classes folder.

Comment: @JamesNapier: I don't know if you are familiar with OOP-programming, but the part about using the constructor and defining a private variable should be pretty straight forward. It allows you to access the class everywhere in your own class, and you just need to include it once.